# Cocos2d Box2d Scaling Radius Circle Bodies

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, geometry, box2d-iphone

Currently, in cocos2d, I have a an app that does the following:

Initiate with a Blank Screen. 
When I tap the screen, I get a circle to pop-up. As I hold the circle, the circle will continue to grow at a constant rate. However, despite the fact that the sprite is growing, the box2d physical body isn't, which means that the sprite will not collide with other bodies. I been trying to figure out a way to change the radius that scales with the sprite but no such question exist here for cocos2d. I have noticed other box2d for things other than cocos2d but I am having a hard time translating them over.

```
//smile.position = ccp(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
smile.scale = .05;
[self addChild:smile];


// b2BodyDef smileBodyDef;

smileBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
smileBodyDef.position.Set(touchLocation.x/PTM_RATIO, touchLocation.y/PTM_RATIO);
smileBodyDef.userData = smile;
smileBody = world->CreateBody(&smileBodyDef);
//Radius
b2CircleShape smileCircleShape;
int radius = 80;

//Fixture
smileFixtureDef.shape = &smileCircleShape;
smileFixtureDef.density = 0.00f;
smileFixtureDef.friction = .2f;
smileBody->CreateFixture(&smileFixtureDef);




if (CGRectContainsPoint(smileRect, touchLocation)) {
growForever = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCScaleBy actionWithDuration: .5 scale:    1.2]];
[growForever setTag:1];
[smile runAction:growForever];
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time you want to change your radius, grab the shape object associated with the b2Fixture that you created for your body, and then set the new value accordingly:

```
fixture->GetShape()->m_radius = new_radius/PTM_RATIO;
```

Comment: Can you explain this? I tried copying and pasting that in but it's telling me new_radius is an unidentified variable.

Comment: new_radius is simply the new radius value of your "smile" sprite. As the "smile" sprite scales, you want the shape's radius to also match the scaled size of the sprite. You can probably get the new_radius value by: [smile boundingBox].size.width * 0.5, if your smile sprite is a perfect circle.

Comment: I've been reading into something about how bodies in Box2d don't scale. You need to destroy the bodies and reapply new bodies... can you elaborate on this?

Comment: One way, as mentioned in my answer, is to simply modify the existing fixture of the body. To ensure that the mass characteristics are adjusted accordingly, you might want to do:  body->ResetMassData(); Alternatively, a cleaner way would be to destroy the fixture and recreate a new one with a larger size, and reassign it back to the body.